# Pandas Vs SQL Speed

Tags: sql, sqlite, pandas

I'm hearing different views on when one should use Pandas vs when to use SQL.

I tried to do the following in Pandas on 19,150,869 rows of data:

```
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    tmp = int((int(row['M']) / PeriodGranularity))+1
    row['TimeSlot'] = str(row["D"]+1) + "-" + str(row["H"]) + "-" + str(tmp)
```

And found it was taking so long I had to abort after 20 minutes.

I performed the following in SQLLite:

```
Select strftime('%w',PlayedTimestamp)+1 as D,strftime('%H',PlayedTimestamp) as H,strftime('%M',PlayedTimestamp) as M,cast(strftime('%M',PlayedTimestamp) / 15+1 as int) as TimeSlot from tblMain
```

and found it took 4 seconds ("19150869 rows returned in 2445ms").

Note:
For the Pandas code I ran this in the step before it to get the data from the db:

```
sqlStr = "Select strftime('%w',PlayedTimestamp)+1 as D,strftime('%H',PlayedTimestamp) as H,strftime('%M',PlayedTimestamp) as M from tblMain"
df = pd.read_sql_query(sqlStr, con)
```

Is it my coding that's at fault here or is it generally accepted that for certain tasks SQL is a lot faster?

Comment: iterrows is really bad choice, slowiest looping in pandas...

Comment: Thanks yeah - I found itertuples to be a LOT quicker than iterrows.

Answer (score 9):

It seems you can use vectorize solution (`PeriodGranularity` is some variable):

```
df['TimeSlot'] = (df["D"]+1).astype(str) + "-" + 
                  df["H"].astype(str) + "-" + 
                 ((df['M'].astype(int) / PeriodGranularity).astype(int)+1).astype(str)
```

And for parse `datetime` to `str` use [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html).

[`DataFrame.iterrows`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html)is really slow - check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24870953/does-iterrows-have-performance-issues/24871316#24871316).

First some [comaprison of code for users coming from SQL background](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/comparison_with_sql.html).

Comapring 2 technologies is really hard and I am not sure if some nice answer in SO (too broad reasons), but I find [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/1tqjt4/why_do_you_use_pandas_instead_of_sql/).

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses, appreciated. Giving it a whirl. Ps. Think you meant to write .astype(str) at the end there?

Comment: I add it because `str(tmp)`

Comment: Ok the results are in, the above method took 90 seconds. Definitely an improvement but not as fast as 3 seconds for SQLLite. I also checked my memory usage during the time and it hovered around 65%. Anyway was an interesting little exercise to help me make form a view. Happy to benchmark other alternatives if people have it, but generally I'm leaning towards SQLLite for this task.

Comment: Hmmm, it is also hard question if `database` like `SQLLite` or `pandas` is better/faster. In my opinion some task can be better/easier/faster in [sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/comparison_with_sql.html), but some are simplier implemented in pandas (e.g. `pivot`). But I have no sql background, so better comparison is hard for me.

Comment: I see this is the accepted answer, even though it doesn't answer the question at all. I wanted to find out when it would be beneficial to choose SQL over Pandas, or vice versa.

Comment: @wobbily_col - it is not accepted, not nike sign. I try improve it.

Comment: @wobbily_col - Iedit answer, please check it. Not sure if need something more complex...

Comment: I am looking for more users experience than a syntax comparison. I saw a couple of posts saying that Pandas was fine until the data set wouldn't fit in memory for example (with SQL it's usually fine while the index fits in memory, so I could see that being a plus for SQL, but more detail would be preferred). String handling is way nicer in Python than in SQL.

Comment: @wobbily_col - very hard question for me, especially I have no sql background. So not so easy answering for me :( But in my opinion if need data processing with small data (check Highlights in [bottom of page](http://pandas.pydata.org/index.html)). And maybe help also [this](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-pandas-and-SQL)

Answer (score 2):

Pandas dataframes are not meant to be iterated this way. [This](https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6?gi=e1d69b07526c) is an excellent source to better understand what should be used for efficiency. In short, numpy vectorization is the way to go whenever possible, otherwise pandas apply() function is still many times faster than iterrows().
Would be interesting to see the comparison results after refactoring.