# Fastest way to tokenize millions of examples?

Tags: python, pandas, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

I am looking to speed up using huggingface's tokenizer to tokenizer millions of examples.

Currently I am using a pandas column of strings and tokenizing it by defining a function with the tokenization operation, and using that with pandas `map` to transform my column of texts.

It's a slow process when I have millions of rows of texts, and I am wondering if there's a faster way to tokenize all my training examples.

I am not limited to pandas in particular.

Comment: this may help ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44695020/pandas-vs-sql-speed

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try [swifter](https://github.com/jmcarpenter2/swifter/blob/master/docs/documentation.md#7-pandasdataframeswifterset_npartitionsnpartitionsnoneapply) to use multiprocess on applying pandas.

EDIT

Here is my sample code.

```
num_processors = 5
def do_something(text):
    pass

df['text'].swifter.set_npartitions(num_processors).apply(do_something)
```

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.

Comment: This doesn't seem to give an increase of speed for my case. I might have something to do with the tokenizer coming from a different library, and that library being a wrapper for code in the Rust programming language.